# Angular2 Meteor, how to insert meta tags in head?

Tags: meteor, angular, meta, angular2-meteor

There are examples of how to do this by just adding another file with `<head><meta whatever-ya-need></head>` in other Meteor stacks(Angular,Blaze,etc)  The file would have to be outside of your templates.  It just concatenates from looking in various files to different parts of your html.

If you attempt this in Angular 2 you will get an error thrown that it can not find `<app></app>`.  I have tried putting an html file with `<head><meta whatever-ya-need></head>` in the initial client directory, in the components directory, and also tried to do it as index.html.  I also put the `<app></app>` tags in that index.html.

Anyone have any ideas of how to inject this or manipulation of a file?

This would also be useful for `<title></title>` and so forth or anything in the `<head>` for that matter.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I had scoured most of the internet, but I did find a resolution for this.  Basically you need to make an index.html in the root of your client folder. `<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <app></app>
</body>`   Do not try to add anything inside of your `<app>` tag.  if you just add `<head>` this will not work and gives you an error.  You will have to add your template through the `@View`.  Hope this helps someone that runs across same issue.

Comment: thanks, Christopher, you saved my day!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I actually came from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979443/image-sometimes-does-not-show-in-angular2) and found Christopher's comment.

From [angular2-meteor tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping), we know if we called the app selector — app, you can get rid of **index.html**. The angular2-meteor package adds default layout with the `<app>` tag automatically as follows:

```
<body>
  <app></app>
</body>
```

But now we still need use `<head>`, so we can create an **index.html** file and use `<base>`, `<meta>`, etc. anything you want.

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta whatever-ya-need>
</head>

<body>
  <app></app>
</body>
```