# Image sometimes does not show in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an image `<img src="image.png">`.

When I use `this._router.navigate(['/Home']);`, sometimes, the image in the page won't show. Instead it shows like this:

[image]

I tried to change to this:

```
this._ngZone.run(() => {
    this._router.navigate(['/Home']);
});
```

But it does not work. What can potentially cause this? Thanks

Comment: Path is the problem. Use base href and use paths as per base href

Comment: @Gary where should I use base href? thanks

Comment: `<head><base href="/"></head>` Use that as the fist line after head. after that use the paths of image as per the server path of the `/` path(html file). Dont use HashStrategy

Comment: thanks @Gary , it is working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Use that as the first line after head.

After that use the paths of image as per the server path of the / path(html file). Dont use HashStrategy!